# could anyone give a simple python for explaining the "Hollywood principle"/inversion of control

Tags: python, inversion-of-control, twisted

I'm very interested in the Twisted web framework. As far as I know the framework
uses the Hollywood principle. I just know the term but totally have no
idea about this design pattern.
I have done a lot of Google searching on the implementation of the
Hollywood principle in Python. But there were few results.
Could any one show me some simple python code to describe this design pattern?

Comment: It's not specific to Python: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle

Comment: I just came here because i hate the name "hollywood principle" so much. Please call it `callback` or *something completely normal for a language with first class functions*.

Answer (score 6):

I've actually never heard the phrase "Hollywood principle" before, nor am I familiar with Twisted (though I feel I should be). But the concept of inversion of control isn't so difficult. I think GUI programming is a good way to introduce it. Consider the following from [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/hello-again.htm) (slightly modified).

```
import Tkinter

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Tkinter.Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Tkinter.Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This is a very simple example of inversion of control. It uses *callbacks* -- hence the [Hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Principle) moniker (thanks Sven for the link). The idea is that you write a function, but you never call it. Instead, you hand it over to another program and tell that program when to call it. Then you give control to that program. Here's a detailed explanation of the code:

```
import Tkinter

class App(object):
```

We start with a class definition, which will hold our callbacks and pass them to the appropriate parts of what I'll call the "master program."

```
    def __init__(self, master):
```

Our class needs a "master program"; the master program is what will call the functions we define. In this case, it's the root window of the GUI. More properly, in the context of GUI programming, we might say that `master` is the *parent* of `frame`.

```
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
```

These two lines create a `Frame` object, which is essentially a box that contains widgets.  You'll see what a widget is in a second. As you can see, it also has a parent -- the same one as our `App`'s: `master`.

```
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(frame, text="QUIT", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)
```

`self.button` is a widget. When you create it with `Tkinter.Button`, you give it some properties, like a label (`text="QUIT"`). You also tell it what its parent is -- in this case, not `master`, but `frame`. So now we have a hierarchy -- `master -> frame -> button`. But the most important thing we do is this: `command=frame.quit`. This tells the button what to do when it is activated by a mouse click. This is, in short, a callback. Here, we pass it the `frame`'s `quit` method, which in this case causes the whole program to quit. Note that the function is not followed by `()` -- that's because we *don't* want to call it. We just want to hand it over to `button`.

```
        self.hi_there = Tkinter.Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)
```

This is another widget that is almost identical to the first, the only exception being that instead of passing `self.quit` as a callback, we've passed `self.say_hi`. Since this is defined below, you could substitute any function you wanted here. (In both the above sets of lines, `self.button.pack` just tells the `Button` where it should go in `frame`.)

```
    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"
```

`say_hi` is where you define what the `Hello` button does.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
```

Now we invoke our class, creating an instance. We create the root window, and then create an `App` instance with `root` as its parent.

```
root.mainloop()
```

And then we're done. We pass control to Tkinter, which does the rest of the work.

Comment: I believe the term "Hollywood Principle" comes from the saying "Don't call us, we'll call you", which pretty much sums up inversion of control.

Comment: @hammar, yeah Sven's comment on the original question explained that part for me. Not sure why I'd never encountered that phrase before...

Answer (score 2):

Twisted is designed with an asynchronous approach.  Your program causes something to happen, but instead of waiting for that thing to happen, it passes control back to the twisted event loop ('reactor' in twisted parlance).  When the reactor finds that something needs your attention, it will invoke your program with the 'callback' you supplied when you originally invoked the action.   The basic workflow looks like this.  First,

```
something_deferred = make.twisted.do.something()
```

the `something_deferred` is usually a `twisted.internet.defer.Deferred` instance that represents the result of `something()`.  Usually, `something()` takes some time to complete, and so the deferred object doesn't yet have the results, even though `something()` returned immediately.   What you then have to do is define a function that twisted can call once the result is actually ready.

```
def something_callback(result):
    do_something_else(result)
```

In most cases, you should also define a function that handles the case that an error occured in `something()`,

```
def something_errback(fault):
    cleanup_something()
```

Finally, you have to tell twisted that you want it to use those functions when `something()` is finally ready.

```
something_deferred.addCallbacks(something_callback, something_errback)
```

Note that you don't call the functions yourself, you just pass their names to `addCallbacks()`.  Twisted is itself responsible for calling your functions.

Not every example follows this exact pattern, but in most cases, you put an instance method in a class that implements a twisted defined interface, or pass a callable to twisted functions that produce events.

Answer (score 2):

The "hollywood principle" is so named because, in the movie industry in Hollywood, nervous first-time actors sometimes call the studio over and over again after an audition, to see if they got the part.  In software development we call this [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29), and it's super inefficient.  In the Hollywood metaphor, it wastes even a successful applicant's time (because they may call repeatedly before the selection has been made) and it wastes the studios time (because many applications who were not selected will nevertheless call them).

Here's a Python file which hopefully illuminates the principle in action:

First, we have an `Actor`, who can perform for an audition, or get a part:

```
class Actor(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def youGotThePart(self):
        print self.name, "got the part."

    def perform(self):
        print self.name, "performs an audition."
```

Then, we have the casting process:

```
applicants = []
def audition(actor):
    actor.perform()
    applicants.append(actor)

def cast():
    import random
    selection = random.choice(applicants)
    selection.youGotThePart()
```

An audition asks an actor to perform, and when casting happens, an actor is selected (at random - as a non-participant in Hollywood's process, I suspect this is probably the most realistic simulation).  That actor then gets notified (the studio "calls" them).

And finally, here's the whole casting process:

```
alice = Actor("alice")
bob = Actor("bob")
carol = Actor("carol")
dave = Actor("dave")

audition(alice)
audition(bob)
audition(carol)
audition(dave)

cast()
```

As you can see, this is very simple and doesn't involve GUIs or networks or any other external sources of input.  It's just a way to structure your code to avoid wasteful checking and re-checking of the same state.  If you think about structuring this program to *not* follow the principle in question, you'd have a loop something like this:

```
while True:
    for actor in alice, bob, carol, dave:
        if actor.didIGetThePart():
            break
    maybeGiveSomeoneThePart()
```

which is of course very wasteful, since who knows how many times the actors might make those calls before the studio chooses?